# php mysql select date from 1 day ago, upto the minute

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I want to capture data that took place at the same hour and minute 24 hours ago. the formula below does not work. what could be the truth?
I will draw the date range in a single line, not listing.

```
$now=time();
$24hrb=$now-(24*60*60);
$que = $connc->query("select * from table where datetime='$24hrb';")
```

Comment: Assuming `datetime` is a field in the database.. Presumably it is in the format `Y-m-d H:i:s` where as `$24hrb` is in the format of seconds since the start of 1970?

Comment: @steven yes. datetime format Y-m-d H:i:s. All I need is the data saved in the database at the same minute 1 hour ago. For example, right now 2021-01-23 13:07, I need the data on 2021-01-23 12:07. but not as a list. only data for that hour and minute. seconds don't matter

Comment: @user3783243 I tried it, it is listed. I only need one line of data in the relevant hour and minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion it would be best to do this all in SQL. You can use the mysql `interval`s options to reduce by 1 day then `like` and `substr` to trim the seconds off and only pull the datetime through the minute value.

```
select * from table where datetime like concat(substr((now() - interval 1 day), 1, 16), '%')
```

The `substr` is taking from a string like this:

```
2021/01/22 11:12:21
^              ^
```

and `concat` throws the wildcard on the end so anything after that matches. So your `like` is processed as:

```
2021/01/22 11:12%
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $24hrb=time() - (24*60*60);
> ```

This is a Timestamp value. But you state in comments:

> yes. datetime format Y-m-d H:i:s

So what you actually should be doing if you insist on using this method is converting your `datetime` to a [**Unix timestamp**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp):

```
$que = $connc->query("SELECT * FROM table 
       WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`datetime_column`) = '".(int)$24hrb."'");
```

This is much better and easier to read than messing around with concatenations and string manipulations.

## Further,

You can extend this action using the [MySQL `BETWEEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) keyword so that you can get the values found between the range of times, say +/- 30 seconds. so:

```
$que = $connc->query("SELECT * FROM table 
       WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`datetime_column`) 
       BETWEEN ".($24hrb - 30)." AND ".($24hrb + 30));
```